# Copy all folders with name "ABC" to another location

Tags: command-line

I have 100 folders and every folder has a subfolder called "ABC". I want to copy folder structure and contents of "ABC" to another location.

How can I do it through Ubuntu terminal?

Comment: cp -R  source  dest

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd use a find command something like this to target the deeper ABC directory, then `mkdir -p` to handle the directory structure, and finally `rsync` to mirror the contents (especially useful if you want to sync this up in the future).

```
find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name ABC \
-exec mkdir -p ../target/{} \; \
-exec rsync -a {}/ ../target/{}/ \;
```

Here's a test:

```
$ mkdir -p input/dir{1,2,3}/{ABC,DEF} target
$ touch input/dir{1,2,3}/{ABC,DEF}/file
$ tree
.
├── input
│   ├── dir1
│   │   ├── ABC
│   │   │   └── file
│   │   └── DEF
│   │       └── file
│   ├── dir2
│   │   ├── ABC
│   │   │   └── file
│   │   └── DEF
│   │       └── file
│   └── dir3
│       ├── ABC
│       │   └── file
│       └── DEF
│           └── file
└── target

$ cd input # we need to be in the parent dir for this to work
$ find . -mindepth 2 -maxdepth 2 -type d -name ABC -exec mkdir -p ../target/{} \; -exec rsync -a {}/ ../target/{}/ \;

$ tree ../target/
../target/
├── dir1
│   └── ABC
│       └── file
├── dir2
│   └── ABC
│       └── file
└── dir3
    └── ABC
        └── file
```

---

You can also do this with a single `rsync` command:

```
$ rsync -rv --include '*/ABC/' --include '*/ABC/*' --exclude '*/*' . ../target
sending incremental file list
dir1/
dir1/ABC/
dir1/ABC/file
dir2/
dir2/ABC/
dir2/ABC/file
dir3/
dir3/ABC/
dir3/ABC/file
```